# stack horizontally a list to another 2d array with different size of lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, graph

Graph G is a connected graph where all nodes are connected to each other.

This is the code for printing all the possible paths in a graph from start to end.

```
#utility function
def AllPathsUtil(graph, u, d, visited, path, tours, num_nodes):

    visited[u] = True
    path.append(u)

    if u == d:
        tours.append(copy.deepcopy(path) )
    else:
        for i in graph[u]:
            if visited[i] == False:
                AllPathsUtil(graph, i, d, visited, path, tours, num_nodes)
    path.pop()
    visited[u] = False

#function to print all the paths
def AllPaths(graph, source, destination):

    tours = []
    V = len(graph.nodes)
    visited = [False]*(V)
    path = []

    AllPathsUtil(graph, source, destination, visited, path, tours, v)

    return tours
```

All the edges of the graph have some weight.

```
paths = AllPaths(G, 1, 4)
```

The output of paths:

```
[[1, 0, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 0, 2, 4],
 [1, 0, 3, 2, 4],
 [1, 0, 3, 4],
 [1, 0, 4],
 [1, 2, 0, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 0, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 4],
 [1, 3, 0, 2, 4],
 [1, 3, 0, 4],
 [1, 3, 2, 0, 4],
 [1, 3, 2, 4],
 [1, 3, 4],
 [1, 4]]
```

I need to horizontally stack the distance traveled along these nodes in front of each of these above-given lists in the output.

This is the list I want to stack.
created it using numpy.array

```
array([2237.01769566, 1382.74116901, 2149.67521107, 1607.04086011,
        689.60948356, 1737.95327849,  820.52190194, 1587.455944  ,
       1571.43780397,  717.16127732, 1959.38087923, 1266.24919378,
       1896.22602933, 1792.86540471, 1250.23105375,  642.75111824])
```

Any way to do this?? Please, help.

Comment: do you want `list(map(list, zip(arr, paths)))` (with `arr` your numpy array)?

Comment: I do want this, but I want to store the result in a NumPy array.

Comment: a numpy array is a bad choice as you have different numbers of items